# Focus to a particular div on window onload

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, setfocus, onload-event

I have recently made a horizontal and vertical scrolling site using jquery.scrollTo

On the website, i have an enter page. Once you enter, fixed navigation appears and depending upon the links , site moves here and there. This navigation remains invisible using ('#my div').hide();

I show it once the user enter the site.

But the prob is that if u reload the site(which ppl will do in case they get their internet disconneted), it remains at the same place where it was last time.. So, i am lying at an arbit position place on every reload without the navigation buttons..

So, i am searching for some alternatives so that i can make sure that the page always starts with enter page irrespective of where he was initially...

Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well, this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

This code will take to the top of the page everytime the window loads.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: hmm..that shld have worked...But its not working. On loading it starts with (0,0). but then after complete loading gets redirected to the previous div. Is the click event handler is stored in cache ?? Why is it happening ??

Comment: You may have some other javascript that scrolls the page. Check it carefully, I think it's the only way it can happen